# Sortablejs, how can I set id on dynamic list

Tags: javascript, svelte, sortablejs

I'm using the Sortablejs library for the drag/ drop/ reorganize feature and I'm having trouble setting id's on a dynamic list on start up.

I am able to set numbered id's to be used for indexing after updating the list with the onChange function, but none of the onstart/onload/etc functions seem to be working for me. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
<script>
    import Sortable from "svelte-sortable";

    //svelte store array that will be of unknown length
    import { items } from "../store/links";

   //Sortable Options
    const options = {
        animation: 150,
        dataIdAttr: "data-id",
        onChange: function (evt) {
            [].forEach.call(
                evt.from.getElementsByClassName("sortable_item"),
                function (el, index) {
                    el.setAttribute("id", index);
                }
            );
        },
    };
</script>


<Sortable items={$items} let:item {options}>
    <div class="sortable_item">
        {item.item}
    </div>
</Sortable>
```

edit: so in svelte when creating dynamic divs and IDs you can do something like below. Items can be of unknown length and  Index is automatically generated here.
I'm simply wondering if I can do something similar with Sortablejs.

```
{#each items as item, index}
<div id={index.toString()}>{item}</div>
{/each}
```

Comment: What is the point of setting the ID to an index that will change anyway?

Comment: It'll be used for indexing. updated the question.